tengo dos pestañas en tkinter y a cada una le hice un menú pero no se como colocarle el menú correspondiente a cada frame
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from client.gui_app import Frame_estudiantes, barra_menu_estudiantes
from client.gui_app2 import Frame_representantes, barra_menu_representantes

def main():
    # creacion de ventana
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Lista de Estudiantes y Representantes")
    root.iconbitmap("img/lists_list_6082.ico")
    root.resizable(0,0)

    # create un notebook
    notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
    notebook.pack(pady=10, expand=True)

    # creando frames
    estudiantes = Frame_estudiantes(root)
    representantes = Frame_representantes(root)

    # creado barras de menú para cada frame
    menu_estudiantes = barra_menu_estudiantes(root)
    menu_representantes = barra_menu_representantes(root)
    
    estudiantes.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    representantes.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

    # add frames to notebook
    notebook.add(estudiantes, text='Estudiantes')
    notebook.add(representantes, text='Representantes')

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Ese es el main de mi programa, y no se como asignar cada menú a cada frame, o hacer un menú interactivo, que cambie por respecto al frame donde me encuentre, si me pueden ayudar se los agradecería.

Si quieres que la barra de menús cambie según la pestaña seleccionada del notebook puedes hacer uso del evento NotebookTabChanged de éste. En la callback que asocies al evento puedes modificar los menús de la barra o cambiarla por otra mediante root.configure(menu=barra_de_menu).
Te dejo un ejemplo reproducible basado en tu código:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk



def main():

    # creacion de ventana
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Lista de Estudiantes y Representantes")
    #root.iconbitmap("img/lists_list_6082.ico")
    root.resizable(0, 0)

    # create un notebook
    notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
    notebook.pack(pady=10, expand=True)

    # creando frames
    estudiantes = tk.Frame(root, width=500, height=250)
    representantes = tk.Frame(root, width=500, height=250)

    # creado barras de menú para cada frame
    menu_estudiantes = tk.Menu(root)
    menu_estudiantes.add_command(label="Estudiantes 1")
    menu_estudiantes.add_command(label="Estudiantes 2")
    
    menu_representantes = tk.Menu(root)
    menu_representantes.add_command(label="Representantes 1")
    menu_representantes.add_command(label="Representantes 2")
    
    estudiantes.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    representantes.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

    # add frames to notebook
    notebook.add(estudiantes, text='Estudiantes')
    notebook.add(representantes, text='Representantes')
    
    def on_tab_changed(_event):
        match notebook.tab(notebook.select(), "text"):
            case "Estudiantes":
                root.configure(menu=menu_estudiantes)
            case "Representantes":
                root.configure(menu=menu_representantes)

    notebook.bind('<<NotebookTabChanged>>', on_tab_changed)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


ttk.Notebook.select() nos retorna la pestaña seleccionada en ese momento, mientras que ttk.Notebook.tab(tab, "text") nos retorna el texto asociado a la pestaña especificada, lo cual nos permite identificarla. Se podria usar también el índice con .index(), pero creo que el nombre es más legible y menos propenso a errores.
